# Вывод данных "наружу" из axios.get

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

```js
const axios = require("axios")

const res = "hello world";

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';
axios.get(apiUrl).then((resp) => {
    res = resp.data
  }
);


console.log(res);
```

Работаю с axios в js для получения данных с сервера node.js. Столкнулся с проблемой, полученные через axios.get данные получается использовать только внутри самой функции(axios.get), как можно вывести эти данные "наружу" для последующего использования?
При запуске закрепленного кода выводит "hello world", хотя должен вывести имя пользователя, в данном случае "Ivan".
Спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете передать результат в калбек функцию к примеру, можете воспользоваться async\await.. "axios async await" в гугле первая же ссылка ваша

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Jour У разных людей разные результаты могут быть при поиске в поисковиках. Потому, если знаете хороший ресурс, где эта проблема решается, то делитесь сразу ссылкой, пожалуйста

Comment: @Духсообщества Я закрепил код и добавил описание результатов его работы.

Comment: @Jour Не получил результатов от такого поиска, возможно конечно я недостаточно порылся, можете пожалуйста дать ссылку на ресурс, который знаете

Comment: начните изучать отсюда https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Comment: const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000')

@EzioMercer А ссылка...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733354/use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-js

Comment: @Jour  Спасибо,попытаюсь разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я смог решить проблему простым изменением структуры кода

```js
const axios = require("axios")

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';
async function start() {
  const a =await axios.get(apiUrl)
  console.log(a.data)
}
start()
```